# No instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono<R> conforms to Flux<ClassA>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following code snippet :

```
    public Flux<ClassA> function(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {

        return classA.functionA(filePartMono)
                .then(classB.functionB(filePartMono))
                .flatMap(paramA -> {
                    return Flux.fromIterable(paramA)
                            .flatMap(paramB ->
                                    classC.functionC(paramB.getField()))
                            .thenMany(classD.functionD(paramA));
                });
    }
```

Return types of above functions :

```
classA.functionA returns Mono<Void>
classB.functionB returns Mono<List<ClassA>>
paramB.getField() is String
classC.functionC returns Mono<Void>
classD.functionD returns Flux<ClassA>
```

I am facing the following error :

```
Required type : Flux<ClassA>
Provided : Mono<Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono<R> conforms to Flux<ClassA>
```

Could someone please tell how to resolve this? Sorry for the naive question. I am beginner to Spring WebFlux and tried to match the return types to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 0):

Since `classD.functionD` is returning `Flux<ClassA>`, needed to use `flatMapMany` instead of `flatMap`.

```
    public Flux<ClassA> function(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {

        return classA.functionA(filePartMono)
                .then(classB.functionB(filePartMono))
                .flatMapMany(paramA -> {
                    return Flux.fromIterable(paramA)
                            .flatMap(paramB ->
                                    classC.functionC(paramB.getField()))
                            .thenMany(classD.functionD(paramA));
                });
    }
```